# How to slide between windows on OS X

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, shortcuts, alt-tab

How does the user at 23 seconds [in this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=8WZr6fvtEgk#t=23s) (possible NSFW language) slide between two different applications like that? Is there a shortcut to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like [Spaces](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1624) to me.

You can turn it on under *System Preferences » View » Exposé and Spaces* and just use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd> or <kbd>←</kbd> to slide back and forth.